# How to selectively intersect certain tables based on certain parameters using SQL in Spring Data?

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have n tables in database, and n parameters corresponding to each table. I have to find the intersection of values between all of those tables for which the corresponding parameter is true.

## Required behaviour

The required behavior is something like this:
Table 1:

```
commonValue1
value1
commonValue2
value2
```

Table 2:

```
value3
commonValue1
value4
commonValue2
```

Table 3:

```
value5
value6
commonValue1
commonValue2
```

Table 4:

```
value7
value8
commonValue1
commonValue2
```

Expected result of the query when `param1 = true, param2 = true, param3 = true, param4 = true`

```
commonValue1
commonValue2
```

Actual result of the query:

```
(empty)
```

## Tried solution

My approach to this was something like:

```
@Query("""
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE :param1 = true
      INTERSECT
   SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE :param2 = true
      INTERSECT
   SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE :param3 = true
      INTERSECT 
   SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE :param4 = true
""")
fun getIntersection(
  @Param("param1") param1: Boolean, 
  @Param("param2") param2: Boolean, 
  @Param("param3") param3: Boolean, 
  @Param("param4") param4: Boolean
): List<ReturnType>
```

But this doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Please provide sample data for each table and required output based on sample data.

Comment: Please provide the code of function getIntersection() to understand the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this.  But one method would be:

```
SELECT val1, val2, common1, common2
FROM ((SELECT t1.*, 1 as which FROM table1 t1 WHERE :param1 = true)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT t2.*, 2 FROM table2 t2 WHERE :param2 = true)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT t3.*, 3 FROM table3 t3 WHERE :param3 = true)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT t4.*, 4 FROM table3 t4 WHERE :param3 = true)
     ) t
GROUP BY val1, val2, common1, common2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT which) = ( (CASE WHEN :param1 = true THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
                                 (CASE WHEN :param2 = true THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
                                 (CASE WHEN :param3 = true THEN 1 ELSE 0) +
                                 (CASE WHEN :param4 = true THEN 1 ELSE 0)
                              );
```

This is not the most efficient method.  The problem with your query is that the subqueries return no rows unless `:param` is `true`.  Hence the intersection is empty.

A better method is to construct the `INTERSECT` query that you need in the application.  The resulting query would not have `:param` values -- it would have only the tables that are needed.